# Ajax and WAMP Server dont mix?

Tags: ajax, wamp

Ive just spent the last hour and a half back n forth on googgle trying to figure out WHY my ajax wasn't refreshing the content past its initial load.

Finally gave up after an hr and spent the last 20 - 30 mins writing up a long question here for help and then it dawned on me " hmmm maybe upload to a real server and test before asking on So. "

sure enough.....it worked the whole time...sigh <--pissed...anyways

***my question*** is, does WAMP automatically not work with Ajax? are there any other settings that need to be changed on the WAMP ini files or...am i missing something?

gonna test in a minute on MAMP but overall ive google mixes of "ajax and wamp xyz " etc but didnt come up with anything related so.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of the cache settings.
Try putting this in a `.htaccess` in the folder that handles the Ajax (only works if you have [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) enabled):

```
Header set Expires "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GM"
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

This essentially disables the cache within browsers. Be careful though, as this also disables caching of images and other static files.

Comment: Hello. Wheen i created a .htaccess file and copy/pasted what you have above and test. i get an "undefined" over and over. any ideas?